# can someone explain to me !lockButton in this jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is partial code from a simple calculator exercise:

From my understanding the ! reverses the boolean value, so since lockButtons was set to false, is it now true in the first if statement? But later below in the if check =, we set lockButtons to true so it stops any numbers from being inputted, it's probably simple but i can't wrap my head around it.

```js
 var firstNumber = "";
      var secondNumber = "";
      var operator = "";
      var result = 0;
      var hasNumber = false;
      var firstNumberComplete = false;
      var lockButtons = false;

      // Check if any button is clicked...
      $(document).on("click", "button", function() {

        // Checks if it's a number and that its not the end of the calculation ("!lockButtons")
        if ($(this).hasClass("number") && !lockButtons) {

          // We'll then set our "hasNumber" variable to true to indicate that we can proceed in selecting an operator.
          hasNumber = true;

          // If we haven't received an operator yet...
          if (firstNumberComplete === false) {

            // Then grab the number of the value clicked and build a string with it
            firstNumber += $(this).attr("value");

            // Print the number to the firstPage
            console.log(firstNumber);

            // Print it to the div
            $("#first-number").html(firstNumber);
          }

          // If we have received an operator already...
          else {

            // Grab the number of the value clicked and build a string with it
            secondNumber += $(this).attr("value");

            // Print the number to the firstPage
            console.log(secondNumber);

            // Print it to the div
            $("#second-number").html(secondNumber);
          }
        }

        // Checks if its an operator (but not "=")
        if ($(this).hasClass("operator") && hasNumber && !lockButtons) {
          firstNumberComplete = true;

          // Set the visual to show the operator's symbol
          $("#operator").html("<h1>" + $(this).text() + "</h1>");
          operator = $(this).attr("value");
        }

        // Checks if the equal button has been pressed. If so...
        if ($(this).hasClass("equal")) {

          // Lock the keyboard from being clicked
          lockButtons = true;
```

Comment: `!lockButtons` does not change the value of `lockButtons`

Comment: so is it just checking if var lockButtons is still false and just saying true, lockButtons is still false?

Comment: `if(!lockButtons)` checks to see if `lockButtons` is `false`. Say it out loud: "if not lockButtons"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lockButtons = false;
```

This statement creates a `boolean` variable which which can have a value of `true` or `false`. So you can use it directly in `if`

```
if(lockbutton)
```

Since `lockbutton` is set to `false` the statements inside `if` will not be executed.

```
if ($(this).hasClass("number") && !lockButtons)
```

This statement should be clear to you. if both the conditions are true then only the statements inside `if` will be executed.

Also I think it's pretty clear why a statement has been put at a particular place by the comments above almost all of them.

Comment: appreciate the more in dept explanation, i understand what its doing but the ! is throwing me off, probably because i haven't used it a good amount

Comment: As bejado says above-Say it out loud "if not `lockButtons`". The statement doesnt assign any value to anything, it is just a test.